Express Js - Only the root route works (/) with the get and post methods. But other routes return a 500 error
I have a Node.js application on a cpanel server. I can only access the main route (/), either in get or post. But none of the other routes work and return a 500 error. Whether the route exists or not, I always get a 500 error.


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
    <p>The server encountered an internal error or
        misconfiguration and was unable to complete
        your request.</p>
    <p>Please contact the server administrator at
        webmaster@....com to inform them of the time this error occurred,
        and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
    <p>More information about this error may be available
        in the server error log.</p>
    <p>Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error
        error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body>

</html>



